# applying jquery multiselect effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using [this jquery plugin](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2014/03/jquery-multiselect-dropdown-list-with-checkboxes.html) to multiple select values.

On create view I properly save data to the db using this plugin. Now I'm struggle to apply loaded values in this plugin.

let's say that I'm passing some data (previously stored using this plugin) from db

```
public ActionResult Demo()
{
    List<MyData> data = _repo.getData();
    return View(data);
}
public class MyData {
    public int[] SelectedData{ get; set; }
    ...
}
```

inside view each input element with this multiple selected values has unique id in order to be properly identified for further process in js function.

```
Demo.cshtml
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
@foreach (var item in Model.SelectedData){
    var multiSelDiv = "multiValues" + index;
    <input id=@multiSelDiv type="text" value="@item.SelectedValues">
}
```

Question is:
how to apply this effect on this loaded data (inside foreach block)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery multiselect` plugin works with `select` items only. You have to render `select` tag with dynamic `options` in your view.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<select class="select">
@foreach (var item in Model.SelectedData){
    var multiSelDiv = "multiValues" + index;
    <option value=@multiSelDiv>@item.SelectedValues</option>
}
<select>
```

On the client side you can select the item by class name and apply the plugin.

```
$('.select').multiselect({

});
```